# differentiate between Windows 10 and Windows 10 IoT

Tags: node.js

Currently I check `process.platform` to know if my software runs on windows or linux to get the right path to the mac address:

```
if(process.platform === "win32"){
        return os.networkInterfaces().Ethernet0[0].mac;
    }else if(process.platform === "linux"){
        return os.networkInterfaces().eth0[0].mac;
    }
```

But I have the problem that windows 10 IoT needs `os.networkInterfaces().Ethernet[0].mac`and also has the `win32` platform.

How can I differentiate between those platforms in a good way?

Comment: What do you mean by "windows 10 **needs** `os.networkInterfaces().Ethernet[0].mac`"?

Comment: require('child_process').execSync('ver').toString().trim() or os.release()

Comment: how about using [address-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/address) or [macaddress-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/macaddress) ?